# DNS doesn't resolve for a specific domain

Tags: mac, dns

For some reason, my Mac can't resolve `discord.com` even with Google or Cloudflare's public DNS, but everything else works just fine.

```
❯ nslookup discord.com 8.8.8.8                                             
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

❯ nslookup discord.com 1.1.1.1                                             
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

❯ nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.200.238
```

The same goes with `dig` and all the browsers I have. I just checked https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/discord.com and it says it's just me. So far `discord.com` is the only domain with problems. Even `discordapp.com` is resolved just fine. I've checked `/etc/hosts` but nothing weird there. What else could be the problem?

Edit:

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like:

```
#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Could you please share the `/etc/resolv.conf` as well ?

Comment: @DhakkanCoder edited!

Answer (score 2):

Check with another ISP (e.g. share mobile connection), looks like discord is blocked.

You can also try enabling encrypted DNS (configuration profiles for macOS/iOS are available here: https://github.com/paulmillr/encrypted-dns)

Comment: Enabling "Use secure DNS" option in Chrome works for me.